# Javascript alert displaying as soon as the page loads

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm a newbee in Javascript.
The error in the following code is that the alert message is displayed as soon as the page loads. Please help me overcome this error. And when I hit the submit button, the alert isn't displayed but rather the next link is opened.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Delete Book</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/default.css" />
</head>
<body id="index_page">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 align="left">Library</h1>
    </div> 
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li id="index"><a href="http://localhost/UID/FAQ.php">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="main_content">
    <h2>Delete book</h2>
 <h4>Enter details of the book</h4>
 <FORM action="del_book_action.php" method="post" >
  <TABLE WIDTH="70%" >

  <TR>
      <TH width="60%">Enter book ID:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" name="id" id="book_id"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH></TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Submit"         onclick="validate_f()"></TD>
  </tr>
  </TABLE>
 </FORM>

</div>
<p id="footer"><a href="http://localhost/UID/UID.php">@AntonyAjay,2012</a></p>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function validate_f()
{
 var y=document.getElementById("book_id").value;
 if(y==""||isNaN(x))
{
alert("Book Id should be numeric");
}
 }
</script>

 </body> 
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if changing `isNaN(x)` to `isNaN(y)` fixes things.

Comment: Agreed with what the others said about not doing this in onload.  But the isNan(x) referring to a non existing value is guaranteed to make the alert fire in the code that you had in the question.

Comment: Hey this solution worked. Just made a silly error in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You're running the function on page load. Change this:

```
window.onload=function validate_f()
```

to:

```
function validate_f()
```

Comment: I changed it but still the error persisted. Finally I got it resolved by the end of this post

Answer (score 0):

Remove the windows on load the intention of the code is to validate upon submit. What is happening is that the function is being called upon page load

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling the function onclick. Make two changes.Don't use the function on load. Use below html change and script

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Submit" onclick="return validate_f()">

    function validate_f()
{
 var y=document.getElementById("book_id").value;
 if(y==""||isNaN(x))
{
alert("Book Id should be numeric");
return false;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass a reference to a function to the window.onload and not the actual call.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
 alert('test');
}
</script>
```